# Seeking an implementation of the Satoh algorithm for elliptical curve point counting

Tags: elliptic-curves, reference-request, implementation, finite-field

I would be very grateful if someone has an implementation of the [Satoh algorithm](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071579702000138) (Fast Elliptic Curve Point Counting). Can someone point me to practical algorithm implementations or provide some examples? Everything I can find is just an article.